# Value attribute of button not passed when icon is clicked directly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, jinja2

I have an html button created using bootstrap that is essentially an Icon used to toggle the state of an item on a website.

```html
<button class='btn' value='${noteid}' onclick='toggleAck(event)'><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></button>
```

When it is clicked a request is fired:

```js
function toggleAck(event) {
            const noteid = event.target.value
            console.log(event.target)
            $.post({
                    url: `/note/${noteid}/toggleacknowledge`,
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                (response) => {
                    if (!response.success) {
                        alert("Failed to mark as read")
                    }
                    refreshNotes()
                }
            )
        }
```

regardless of whether I click the button or the icon, the toggleAck event triggers. However, if I click the icon directly instead of the button the `value` attribute is not passed and the function fails.

How can I fix this HTML so that the value is passed regardless of where the user clicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` is on the button, but the [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) is the element that triggered the event so when you click the icon it tries to retrieve the value from the icon.

Instead use [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) to get the value from the element to which the listener is attached.

```
const noteid = event.currentTarget.value;
```

```js
function toggleAck(event) {
  console.log('target: ', event.target, event.target.value);
  console.log('currentTarget: ', event.currentTarget, event.currentTarget.value);
}
```

```html
<button class='btn' value='${noteid}' onclick='toggleAck(event)'><i class="fas fa-eye">icon</i></button>
```